# Parse String to Jason C# - can't access due to protection level -JObject

Tags: json, parsing, c#-3.0

Hey i want to parse a String to a Jason Object in C#.

I have found this code but i alltimes get the problem that it means for JObject:
"can't access due to protection level c#"
Its because JObject is Internal in this Framework i think. But i found online so much solution and they tell all to make it like below. I dont know what i make wrong.

```
        string APIUrlRandomNameGenerator = "https://api.parser.name/api";
        var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(APIUrlRandomNameGenerator);

        var jobj = new JObject();
        dynamic data = JObject.Parse(json);
        Console.WriteLine(data.id);
        Console.WriteLine(data.first_name);
        Console.WriteLine(data.last_name);
        Console.WriteLine(data.gender);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I was only using the using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq; and i was able to look for the definitions but i it was needed to install the Newtonsoft Paket.

Answer (score 0):

You don'nt need to install any extra packages. Try this

```
    var jsonParsed = JObject.Parse(json);
    Console.WriteLine(jsonParsed["id"]);
    Console.WriteLine(jsonParsed["first_name"]);
    Console.WriteLine(jsonParsed["last_name"]);
    Console.WriteLine(jsonParsed["gender"]);
```